# After fetching the api, I see error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined" in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component called App. I want to send the data that i took from the api(it includes random questions and answers) to child component.In child componenet(QuestionGrid), when i want to take the first question inside the array that come from api, I face the error. i want to use   `console.log(items[0].question)` to see the first question but it fires error.But when I use `console.log(items)` it allow me to see them. I also aware of taking the data after they loaded.I used also **useEffect**. Here is my parent component

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import QuestionGrid from './components/QuestionGrid';
function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=40&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result.results);
        },
    
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])
  
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
  <QuestionGrid isLoaded={isLoaded} items={items}/>      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my child component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
export default function QuestionGrid({ isLoaded, items }) {

   if(isLoaded){
       console.log(items[0].question)
   }


  return isLoaded ? 
  <section className="cards">

      </section> : <h1>Loading</h1>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will fire and error because the initial state of `items` is an empty array. And there is no indexes and object on the `items` state on the first render.

you can check if the the items is loaded by only checking its length.

```
return items.length > 0 ? <h1>your jsx component</h1> : <span>Loading...</span>
```

Comment: so how can I avoid it?  Should I put a question inside the item?

Comment: actually you dont need the `isLoaded` state you just have to check the length of the items to render an component or loading component

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you should use the .catch() in fetch like:

```
fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=40&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result.results);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
      )}
       
      )
```

You are checking for `isLoaded` but not if there is any data. You are setting `isLoaded(true)` in both your result and also in error (which is not bad).

The error is caused because there is nothing in items[0]. To check for this you can call `console.log(items?.[0].question)` or you can make the check in your if-condition `if(items.length > 0)`